# How come PK/Alien realizes that Sarfaraz did not write the letter?

Tags: plot-explanation, pk

In the movie PK, Tapasvi predicts that Sarfaraz will betray the Jaggu. And then Jaggu believes that Sarfaraz has betrayed her and left her at the altar with just a letter. Later, when Tapasvi refers this fact that he predicted this already to Jaggu. Then PK (alien) reveals that Sarfaraz has not betrayed her. But how come he came to know this? He never knew Sarfaraz, he just read the Jaggu's mind. But she believes otherwise.
Does PK sees something in her memory that she herself doesn't know?